# Javascript : replace string at specific position

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a String like that :

```
var str = "Hello, it is a <test>12345</test> and it's fun";
```

I would like to replace "12345" by "****".

The script must take into account the fact that the **string containing between  and  is never the same.**

Comment: Alright I think I can answer this, but are you saying that the replaced string will always be between <test> and </test>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
str = str.replace(/(<test>).*?(?=<\/test>)/, '$1*****');
//=> "Hello, it is a <test>*****</test> and it's fun"
```

If you don't want lookahead then use capturing groups on both sides:

```
str = str.replace(/(<test>).*?(<\/test>)/, '$1*****$2');
//=> "Hello, it is a <test>*****</test> and it's fun"
```

Answer (score 1):

If digits won't always be wrapped between a `<test>` tag, here's another way to solve the same problem.

```
var str = "Hello, it is a <test>12345</test> and it's fun";

var numberPattern = /(\<\w+\>)(\d+)(\<\/\w+\>)/gi;

str = str.replace(numberPattern, "$1****$3");

// str is now "Hello, it is a <test>****</test> and it's fun"
```